# Partial Derivative Leads to Contradiction

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Starting from the same equation $g(x,y,c) = 0$, I partially differentiate with regards to c and end up in a contradiction. However, if I manipulate the equation a bit I do not. I will post the entire solution, which starts from an ODE.
$$(3y-a)^2*y\prime^2 - 4y = 0$$
$$y\prime = +(\frac{4y}{3y-a})^{1/2}, or\ y\prime = -(\frac{4y}{3y-a})^{1/2}$$
$$solving\ both\ ODEs: y^{3/2} - ay^{1/2} = \pm*x + c \quad (1)$$
$$(1)\rightarrow y^{3/2} - ay^{1/2}  \mp*x - c = 0 \quad let\ g_1(x,y,c) = y^{3/2} - ay^{1/2}  \mp*x - c = 0 \quad (2)$$
$$(1)\rightarrow (y^{3/2} - ay^{1/2})^2 = (\pm*x + c)^2 $$
$$\Leftrightarrow y*(y^3-a)^2 = (\pm*x + c)^2 \quad let\ g_2(x,y,c) = y*(y^3-a)^2 - (\pm*x + c)^2 = 0 \quad (3)$$

Now if we try and diferentiate both  $g_1$ and $g_2$ partialy with regards to c we end up with the following:

$$(2) \rightarrow -1 = 0$$
$$(3) \rightarrow c = \mp x$$

So my question really is, why can I not partially differentiate (2)? I know from where I got this question that (3) is the correct way to go, but why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression $g(x,y,c)=0$ does not specify the function. It specifies the value which the function must have (from its range of possible values) to solve the DE, but that is not the same thing. The function $g(x,y,c)$ will have value $0$ for particular values of the three quantities $x$, $y$, and $c$, and the equation $g(x,y,c)=0$ can be used to find relationships between the values of $x$, $y$ and $c$ Which solve it.

The function $g$ is not identically zero; it takes other values for suitable values of the three variables. To partially differentiate a function with respect to a variable requires changing that variable without changing the other variables. However the condition $g=0$ contradicts the requirement of changing only one variable at a time so doing a simple partial derivative violates this condition. In other words the process of performing the partial differentiation assumes that there are values of $x$, $y$ and $c$ for which $g=0$ is false.

We can instead do a more complex process where we take into account the changes to the other variables. In your question, if you change $c$ and keep $y$ constant then $x$ cannot be constant (in fact $x=\pm c$), so you must include the partial derivative $\frac{\partial x}{\partial c}$ to account for changes in $x$.

Comment: Question: could I instead of keeping y constant and chaning x,c keep x constant and change y,c?

Comment: Yes you could. I chose $y$ to keep constant only because it gave a simpler equation for $x$.

Answer (score 1):

There is no contradiction. The equation (3) holds the information of equation (2) but unadvisedly expanded your solution domain. In other words, when you have chosen to use exponentiation, $ -(y^{3/2} - ay^{1/2}) = (\pm*x + c) $ joined $ +(y^{3/2} - ay^{1/2}) = (\pm*x + c) $ as a "possible" solution.

Do the same thing in the context of simpler equations like $x=2$ and you will end up with $x=\pm\,2$, for example.